# Configure Converter for RetrofitSpiceService

Tags: android, converters, retrofit, robospice

I'm using Retrofit 2.0 and Robospice libraries, included in gradle file like this:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
compile 'com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-retrofit:1.4.14'
```

I want to use the `RetrofitGsonSpiceService` but when I run the application I get a `Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: retrofit.converter.GsonConverter`

It's caused by the

```
@Override
    protected Converter createConverter() {
        return  new GsonConverter(new Gson());
    }
```

**method of the `RetrofitGsonSpiceService` class.**

In Retrofit 2.0 the default Converter is now excluded.

My question is do you know a simple way of configuring Robospice to easily work with Retrofit 2.0, or is out there a preconfigured SpiceService to work with the new Retrofit 2.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not so simple as before...

PS. I used Moshi parser, but with GSON it should be similar.

1. You should extend `SpiceService`:

   ```
   public class SpiceNetworkService extends SpiceService {

   private Map<Class<?>, Object> retrofitInterfaceToServiceMap = new HashMap<>();
   protected List<Class<?>> retrofitInterfaceList = new ArrayList<>();

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
       super.onCreate();
       addRetrofitInterface(WallpapersApi.class);
   }

   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   protected <T> T getRetrofitService(Class<T> serviceClass) {
       T service = (T) retrofitInterfaceToServiceMap.get(serviceClass);
       if (service == null) {
           Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                   .baseUrl(getServerUrl())
                   .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
                   .build();
           service = retrofit.create(serviceClass);
           retrofitInterfaceToServiceMap.put(serviceClass, service);
       }
       return service;
   }

   @SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unchecked"})
   @Override
   public void addRequest(CachedSpiceRequest<?> request, Set<RequestListener<?>> listRequestListener) {
       if (request.getSpiceRequest() instanceof RetrofitSpiceRequest) {
           RetrofitSpiceRequest retrofitSpiceRequest = (RetrofitSpiceRequest) request.getSpiceRequest();
           retrofitSpiceRequest.setService(getRetrofitService(retrofitSpiceRequest.getRetrofitedInterfaceClass()));
       }
       super.addRequest(request, listRequestListener);
   }

   public final List<Class<?>> getRetrofitInterfaceList() {
       return retrofitInterfaceList;
   }

   protected void addRetrofitInterface(Class<?> serviceClass) {
       retrofitInterfaceList.add(serviceClass);
   }

   @Override
   public CacheManager createCacheManager(Application application) throws CacheCreationException {
       CacheManager cacheManager = new CacheManager();
       cacheManager.addPersister(new MoshiPersisterFactory(application, getCacheFolder()));
       return cacheManager;
   }

   protected String getServerUrl() {
       return SpiceWallpapersRequest.API_URL;
   }

   public File getCacheFolder() {
       return null;
   }
   ```

   }
2. Implement Persister factory like this:

   ```
   public class MoshiPersisterFactory extends InFileObjectPersisterFactory {
   public MoshiPersisterFactory(Application application) throws CacheCreationException {
       super(application);
   }

   public MoshiPersisterFactory(Application application, File cacheFolder) throws CacheCreationException {
       super(application, cacheFolder);
   }

   public MoshiPersisterFactory(Application application, List<Class<?>> listHandledClasses) throws CacheCreationException {
       super(application, listHandledClasses);
   }

   public MoshiPersisterFactory(Application application, List<Class<?>> listHandledClasses, File cacheFolder) throws CacheCreationException {
       super(application, listHandledClasses, cacheFolder);
   }

   @Override
   public <T> InFileObjectPersister<T> createInFileObjectPersister(Class<T> clazz, File cacheFolder) throws CacheCreationException {
       return new MoshiPersister<>(getApplication(), clazz, cacheFolder);
   }
   ```

   }
3. Finally extend InFileObjectPersister:

   public class MoshiPersister extends InFileObjectPersister {
       public MoshiPersister(Application application, Class clazz) throws CacheCreationException {
           super(application, clazz);
       }

   ```
   public MoshiPersister(Application application, Class<T> clazz, File cacheFolder) throws CacheCreationException {
       super(application, clazz, cacheFolder);
   }

   @Override
   protected T readCacheDataFromFile(File file) throws CacheLoadingException {
       BufferedSource sink = null;

       try {
           InputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
           sink = Okio.buffer(Okio.source(fileInputStream));

           Moshi moshi = new Moshi.Builder().build();
           JsonAdapter<T> jsonAdapter = moshi.adapter(getHandledClass());


           return jsonAdapter.fromJson(sink);
       } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           // Should not occur (we test before if file exists)
           // Do not throw, file is not cached
           Ln.w("file " + file.getAbsolutePath() + " does not exists", e);
           return null;
       } catch (Exception e) {
           throw new CacheLoadingException(e);
       } finally {
           try {
               if (sink != null) {
                   sink.close();
               }
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   }

   @Override
   public T saveDataToCacheAndReturnData(final T data, final Object cacheKey) throws CacheSavingException {
       try {
           if (isAsyncSaveEnabled()) {
               Thread t = new Thread() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                       try {
                           saveData(data, cacheKey);
                       } catch (IOException | CacheSavingException e) {
                           Ln.w("An error occured on saving request " + cacheKey + " data asynchronously");
                       }
                   }
               };
               t.start();
           } else {
               saveData(data, cacheKey);
           }
       } catch (CacheSavingException e) {
           throw e;
       } catch (Exception e) {
           throw new CacheSavingException(e);
       }
       return data;
   }

   private void saveData(T data, Object cacheKey) throws IOException, CacheSavingException {
       Moshi moshi = new Moshi.Builder().build();
       JsonAdapter<T> jsonAdapter = moshi.adapter(getHandledClass());
       BufferedSink sink = new Buffer();
       jsonAdapter.toJson(sink, data);

       FileOutputStream out = null;
       try {
           out = new FileOutputStream(getCacheFile(cacheKey));
           sink.buffer().copyTo(out);
       } finally {
           if (out != null) {
               out.close();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   }